# Изначально сделать блок в одну высоту, затем

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```js
 c.onclick = e =>  document.body.classList.toggle('open');
```

```css
*{
  position: relative;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  outline: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
}
.gl {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.g2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgb(0 0 0);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
}
.open .g2 {transform: unset}
.control {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  transform:  translateY(calc(100% + 10px));
}
  .r {padding: 10px}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="gl"> 
    <div class="g2" id='d'>    
        <button class='control' id='c'>Клик</button>
    </div>
    <div class='r'>Текст</div>
  </div>
<body>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы красный блок изначально принимал высоту дочернего блока с классом 'r', а после того как убираем transform с блока g2, красный блок принимал высоту блока g2?

Так чтобы анимация там и там срабатывала.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `height` в связке с `overflow: hidden`, но для этого необходимо сначала разметить положение элементов с помощью родительских контейнеров (в примере ниже `flex`), а уже в дочерних элементах управлять элементами контента.
В целом, см. разметку ниже.

```js
const toggle = document.querySelector(".popup__toggle")
const content = document.querySelector(".popup__content")

toggle.onclick = () => {
  content.classList.toggle("active")
}
```

```css
*,*::before,*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex {
  display:flex;
  background: red;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex__item:first-child {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.r {
  padding: 10px;
}


.popup__content {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s max-height linear;
}

.popup__toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.active {
  /*стоит 100vh, т.к. мы изначально подразумеваем, что высота этого блока будет не больше высоты экрана*/
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex__item">
    <div class="popup">
      <div class="popup__content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia consequuntur perferendis ab ratione. Commodi obcaecati alias nostrum veniam quas labore ab. Vel magnam tenetur porro optio tempora voluptates nemo iusto?
        Nostrum, distinctio expedita dolor molestias autem corporis, recusandae est minus laboriosam eligendi nesciunt, alias culpa reprehenderit a ullam ipsum eum consequatur officiis. Possimus modi perspiciatis doloremque numquam animi hic cum!
        Deserunt, aperiam voluptatibus sunt excepturi quo quaerat omnis, culpa tempore accusantium eaque illum porro eligendi eius aliquid dolores. Amet, repellendus molestias ducimus consectetur impedit iure? Nam deleniti adipisci vel iusto?
        Repellendus quae deserunt magni maiores, maxime sint architecto tenetur dolores soluta, neque reiciendis aut non incidunt et voluptas sit vitae, nobis atque amet sed adipisci explicabo quia nesciunt. Numquam, corporis.
      </div>
      <div class="popup__control">
        <button class="popup__toggle">toggle</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex__item">
    <div class="r">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```